# Pandas read_excel sometimes creates index even when index_col=None

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to read an excel file into a data frame and I want set the index later, so I don't want pandas to use column 0 for the index values.

By default (`index_col=None`), it shouldn't use column 0 for the index but I find that if there is **no** value in cell A1 of the worksheet it will.

Is there any way to over-ride this behaviour (I am loading many sheets that have no value in cell A1)?

This works as expected when test1.xlsx has the value "DATE" in cell A1:

```
In [19]: pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx')                                             
Out[19]: 
                 DATE         A         B         C
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.766895  1.142639  0.810603
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00  0.605812  0.890286  0.810603
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.623123  1.053022  0.810603
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00  0.740577  1.505082  0.810603
4 2018-01-01 04:00:00  0.335573 -0.024649  0.810603
```

But when the worksheet has no value in cell A1, it automatically assigns column 0 values to the index:

```
In [20]: pd.read_excel('test2.xlsx', index_col=None)                             
Out[20]: 
                            A         B         C
2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.766895  1.142639  0.810603
2018-01-01 01:00:00  0.605812  0.890286  0.810603
2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.623123  1.053022  0.810603
2018-01-01 03:00:00  0.740577  1.505082  0.810603
2018-01-01 04:00:00  0.335573 -0.024649  0.810603
```

This is not what I want.

Desired result: Same as first example (but with 'Unnamed' as the column label perhaps).

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) says

> index_col : int, list of int, default None.
>
> Column (0-indexed) to use as the row labels of the DataFrame. Pass None if there is no such column.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue. I get the desired result when leaving cell A1 blank. This was using pandas 0.24.0. What pandas version are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue that you're describing matches a known pandas bug. This bug was fixed in the recent [pandas 0.24.0 release](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html):

> **Bug Fixes**
>
> - Bug in [read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) in which `index_col=None` was not being respected and parsing index columns anyway ([GH18792](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18792), [GH20480](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20480))

Comment: I'm using pandas version 0.25.3 and it is happening to me.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @DataGirl No. I do not experience this issue in pandas 0.25.3.

Comment: I'm using pandas version 0.25.1. But issue doesn't seem to be resloved. I am getting the index column, no matter what!

Comment: @ChintanGotecha In that case you should report the issue at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues .

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
index_col=0
```

instead of

```
index_col = None
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  Using `index_col=0` will cause `pd.read_excel` to use the first column as the index which is what I am trying to avoid (See first sentence of the question).

Comment: Sorry for not reading well, I think you can hide index when you would like to save or convert it to other formats like  df.to_excel(filename, index=False), I don't find index_col=None working as we expect.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing essentially the same issue since last couple of days.

I have an excel file that also have the first column header as Blank. So when it is read it gets read as an index.

I tried many options but below code works using skiprows instead of the header option. Interestingly skiprows uses the "Unnamed: 0" naming patterns for columns that does not have a header where as using the header option it did not work. We are using pandas version 0.20.1 :

```
df = pd.read_excel( "ABC.xlsx"  , dtype=str, sheetname='Supply', skiprows =6, usecols = mycols )

 df.columns
Index([       'Unnamed: 0', 2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2015-02-01 00:00:00,
       2015-03-01 00:00:00, 2015-04-01 00:00:00, 2015-05-01 00:00:00,
       2015-06-01 00:00:00, 2015-07-01 00:00:00, 2015-08-01 00:00:00,
       2015-09-01 00:00:00,
       ...
       ],
      dtype='object', length=120)
```

The documentation does not provide any more info on this. But above work-around can save your day.