# Remove index from Label entry

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

The code is taking the week input from user, search for the rows that contains that week in an excel file, write the result on a different excel file and from there in write the colums on a tkinter labels. The problem is that on the GUI(Labels) is showing the index value. How can i hide/remove this index value from the GUI(labels)

[image: Picture of GUI]

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import date, datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from warnings import simplefilter
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
import xlrd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

simplefilter("ignore")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
sheet = wb["Productie"]
week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")
root.geometry("1000x500")
fontmare = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight='bold')
var = tk.StringVar()
def exportexcel():
    wb_sales = pd.ExcelFile("excel.xlsx")
    sheet_3 = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", sheet_name= 2,dtype=str)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
    read_sheets_name = wb_sales.sheet_names
    weekenter = var.get()
    print(weekenter)
    print(sheet_3.query("['6'] in Week"))
    global sheetweek
    if weekenter == "6":
        #sheetweek.set(sheet_3.query("['6'] in Week"))
        writer = ExcelWriter('weekexport.xlsx')
        sheet_3.query("['6'] in Week").to_excel(writer, 'Foaie1',index=False,)
        writer.save()
        print(sheet_3.query("['6'] in Week"))
    if weekenter == "7":
        #sheetweek.set(sheet_3.query("['7'] in Week"))
        writer = ExcelWriter('weekexport.xlsx')
        sheet_3.query("['7'] in Week").to_excel(writer, 'Foaie1',index=False,)
        writer.save()
        print(sheet_3.query("['7'] in Week"))

    #####################################################################################################
    global dfM
    global dfB
    global dfQ
    global dfSN1
    global dfSN2
    dfM.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None,  usecols="D",index_col=None))
    dfB.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="E",index_col=None))

    dfQ.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="F",index_col=None))

    dfSN1.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="G",index_col=None))

    dfSN2.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="H",index_col=None))








    root.mainloop()



def write_to_xlsx():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
    sheet = wb["Productie"]
    week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]
    ws = wb.active
    maxim = ws.max_row + 1

    for i in range(8):
        ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=i+1, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=i+1)  # A

    ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=24, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=24)  # X
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=25, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=25)  # Y
    week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]
    ws.cell(column=1, row=maxim, value=week_number)

    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime('%d/%m')
    ws.cell(column=2, row=maxim, value=dt_string)

    for ndex, entry in enumerate(entry_list):
        ws.cell(column=ndex+3, row=maxim, value=entry_list[ndex].get())
        entry_list[ndex].delete(0, 'end')

    rows = range(1, maxim + 1)
    columns = range(1, 8)
    for row in rows:
        for col in columns:
            sheet.cell(row, col).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)

    wb.save("excel.xlsx")


label_list = ['Model', 'Etapa', 'Batch', 'Cantitate', 'S/N']
entry_list = []

for i in range(len(label_list)):
    tk.Label(root, text=label_list[i]).grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(root, width=10))
    entry_list[-1].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='w',)
dfM = StringVar()
dfB = StringVar()
dfQ = StringVar()
dfSN1 = StringVar()
dfSN2 = StringVar()
dfM.set("Model")
dfB.set("Batch")
dfQ.set("Cantitate")
dfSN1.set("Serial")
dfSN2.set("Number")
tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=write_to_xlsx).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='W')
tk.Button(root, text='Week:', command=exportexcel).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='W')
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var, width=10).grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='w')
LabelModel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=dfM, font=fontmare).grid(row=8, column=0,sticky="w")
LabelBatch = tk.Label(root, textvariable=dfB, font=fontmare).grid(row=8, column=1,sticky="w")
LabelQty = tk.Label(root, textvariable=dfQ, font=fontmare).grid(row=8, column=2,sticky="w")
LabelSerial = tk.Label(root, textvariable=dfSN1, font=fontmare).grid(row=8, column=3,sticky="w")
LabelNumber = tk.Label(root, textvariable=dfSN2, font=fontmare).grid(row=8, column=4,sticky="w")



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see one major problem already. You have 2 mainloops. You only ever need one instance of `Tk()` and one `mainloop()`.

Comment: yes, just spotted it, it was from a previous part of the code that I delete it. thank you

Comment: Do you have an example set of data we can use. I am having a hard time testing due to the `week` data not existing in my test excel.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kYx_Pjlzab902BsLSX005yi6JWGBcTUs

Comment: this is the main file (put it in the folder with the program) from extracting the data, the code will create another one in the same folder.

Comment: just one more thing, only use 6 when search for a week, is the only one that works at the moment

Comment: Looks like I have to request access to the file. I will have to wait till I get home to use my personal account as I cannot request from my work account.

Comment: There appears to be a bug report about this problem with `index_col=None`. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488373/7475225).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot I would like to do but I am running out of time today.

There appears to be a bug report about this problem with `index_col=None` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487818/pandas-read-excel-sometimes-creates-index-even-when-index-col-none/54488373#54488373).

Related bug reports: [GH18792](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18792) and [GH20480](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20480)

What I did to get around this issue is to convert the data to a string then break it down into its components. Once I had those I could run a split() again on it to get rid of the index's.

For now here is the fix you are looking for:

Replace:

```
global dfM
    global dfB
    global dfQ
    global dfSN1
    global dfSN2
    dfM.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None,  usecols="D",index_col=None))
    dfB.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="E",index_col=None))
    dfQ.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="F",index_col=None))
    dfSN1.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="G",index_col=None))
    dfSN2.set(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1', header=None, usecols="H",index_col=None))
```

With:

```
var_lst = [dfM, dfB, dfQ, dfSN1, dfSN2]
for ndex, i in enumerate(['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']):
    final_string = ''
    build_list = str(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1',
                                   header=None, usecols=i, index_col=None)).split('\n')
    for string in build_list:
        x = ' '.join(string.split()).split()
        if len(x) > 1:
            final_string = '{} {}\n'.format(final_string, ' '.join(string.split()).split()[1])
    var_lst[ndex].set(final_string)
```

Results:

[image]

On further review:

There are some thing you may want to change. For example you can use global all on one line if need be. `global var1, var2, var3 ...` howeve in your code global is not needed at all.

You already built your entry information dynamically so lets do the same for your labels and other vars.

I have also commented out a few lines that were not being used at all and you code appears to be still working so let me know if you have any issues.

I removed imports that were not being used and did some general cleanup of your code to more closely follow PEP8.

Revised code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from datetime import date, datetime
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from warnings import simplefilter
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl


def export_excel():
    # wb_sales = pd.ExcelFile("excel.xlsx")   # line not used
    sheet_3 = pd.read_excel("excel.xlsx", sheet_name=2, dtype=str)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 500)
    # read_sheets_name = wb_sales.sheet_names  # line not used
    weekenter = var.get()
    if weekenter == "6":
        writer = ExcelWriter('weekexport.xlsx')
        sheet_3.query("['6'] in Week").to_excel(writer, 'Foaie1', index=False)
        writer.save()
    if weekenter == "7":
        writer = ExcelWriter('weekexport.xlsx')
        sheet_3.query("['7'] in Week").to_excel(writer, 'Foaie1', index=False)
        writer.save()

    for ndex, i in enumerate(['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']):
        final_string = ''
        build_list = str(pd.read_excel('weekexport.xlsx', sheet_name='Foaie1',
                                       header=None, usecols=i, index_col=None)).split('\n')
        for string in build_list:
            x = ' '.join(string.split()).split()
            if len(x) > 1:
                final_string = '{} {}\n'.format(final_string, ' '.join(string.split()).split()[1])
        var_list[ndex].set(final_string)


def write_to_xlsx():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
    sheet = wb["Productie"]
    # week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]  # line not used.
    ws = wb.active
    maxim = ws.max_row + 1

    for i in range(8):
        ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=i+1, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=i+1)  # A

    ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=24, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=24)  # X
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=maxim, start_column=25, end_row=maxim + 1, end_column=25)  # Y
    week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]
    ws.cell(column=1, row=maxim, value=week_number)

    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime('%d/%m')
    ws.cell(column=2, row=maxim, value=dt_string)

    for ndex, entry in enumerate(entry_list):
        ws.cell(column=ndex+3, row=maxim, value=entry_list[ndex].get())
        entry_list[ndex].delete(0, 'end')

    rows = range(1, maxim + 1)
    columns = range(1, 8)
    for row in rows:
        for col in columns:
            sheet.cell(row, col).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)
    wb.save("excel.xlsx")


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Menu")
root.geometry("1000x500")
font_mare = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14, weight='bold')
var = tk.StringVar()
simplefilter("ignore")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')
sheet = wb["Productie"]
week_number = date.today().isocalendar()[1]

label_list = ['Model', 'Etapa', 'Batch', 'Cantitate', 'S/N']
entry_list = []

for i in range(len(label_list)):
    tk.Label(root, text=label_list[i]).grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(root, width=10))
    entry_list[-1].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='w')

tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=write_to_xlsx).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='W')
tk.Button(root, text='Week:', command=export_excel).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='W')
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var, width=10).grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='w')

label_list_2 = ['Model', 'Batch', 'Cantitate', 'Serial', 'Number']
var_list = []
for ndex, i in enumerate(label_list_2):
    var_list.append(tk.StringVar(root))
    var_list[-1].set(i)
    tk.Label(root, textvariable=var_list[-1], font=font_mare).grid(row=8, column=ndex, sticky="w")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No problem it is just a matter of converting to string and then parsing the data to fit your needs. Glad to help. I will be posting an update soon for other things I noticed. If my post answered your question please select the check mark next to it so others know you issue is resolved.

Comment: @FilipAdrian I have added a further revision of your code. Let me know if you have any questions.